# How to create an Arquillian test that uses XStream?

Tags: java, xstream, jboss-arquillian

How create an Arquillian test that uses XStream?

How should the deployment method look like?

First thing I tried was adding my classes and the XStream package.

```
ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "myTest.war")
    .addClass(...) // my classes
    .addClass(...) // my classes
    .addPackages(true, "com.thoughtworks.xstream")
    .addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
    .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
```

Got error complaining about missing XStream dependencies, so I added:

```
    .addPackages(true, "org.dom4j")
    .addPackages(true, "org.xmlpull")
```

After that, I'm still getting the following error:

> com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException: Cannot create
>   XmlPullParser     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractXppDriver.createReader(AbstractXppDriver.java:56)
>     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1040)  at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1031) (...)

What else can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your question in the comment above: [ShrinkWrap resolvers](https://github.com/shrinkwrap/resolver) can be the way to go.

```
WebArchive archieve = ShrinkWrap
            .create(WebArchive.class, "myTest.war")
            .addPackages(true, "your.company.project")
            // other resources ...

File[] xstreamLib = Maven.resolver().resolve("com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.7")
            .withTransitivity().asFile();
archieve.addAsLibraries(xstreamLib);
```

Other sample usage [here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowDoIAddJARFilesToTheTestArchive).

Why is this so good? Because of two reasons:

- every library you're using can have its own **transitive dependencies** - so you would have to add it separately (in your case these are: `dom4j` and `xmlpull`) - but there can be a lot more dependencies.
- **repackaging libraries** is extremely error prone, as you've noticed it already.

ShrinkWrap resolvers are really useful piece of software.

Answer (score 2):

It happens that the xmlpull's XmlPullParserFactory needs a special file to be present at the META-INF directory in order to work.

To solve that problem, you need to add the following line when creating the web archive:

```
.addAsResource("META-INF/services/org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory", "META-INF/services/org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory")
```

The working deployment method looks like this:

```
@Deployment
public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "myTest.war")
            .addClass(...) // my classes
            .addClass(...) // my classes
            .addPackages(true, "com.thoughtworks.xstream")
            .addPackages(true, "org.dom4j")
            .addPackages(true, "org.xmlpull")
            .addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAsResource("META-INF/services/org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory", "META-INF/services/org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory")
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");

}
```

It took me some time to figure it out. I hope it helps someone.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem :) But please note also, that when using `XStream` as library added under WAR `lib/` directory - your issue would never have existed.

Comment: @GrzesiekD. It would be great. How could I do that? The XStream dependence is added to my project using maven and the war is created at the deployment method.

Comment: This answer solved my problem using XStream in Tests with wildfly-arquillian-container-remote.